# Service Cloud Live Agent in Customer Community Portal

Tags: case, customer-community, liveagent, servicecloud

Once live agent is setup, can we embed this on the community portal where only certain customers can engage in chat?

We have customer classified as Gold, silver and bronze status and would like to provide chat service for only gold customers.

How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no standard way to achieve this. However you may look at the LIVE AGENT Guides…(links below)

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_administrator.pdf

You can try this customization - 
1. create Visualforce page(for Classic) or a Lightning Component ( for  Lightning)

2. For CLassic: Try and Use  the"RENDER" function on this page and render the LIVE AGENT 
   CHAT only for the customers based on your logic.

   For LIGHTNING: Use "AURA:IF function" render the LIVE AGENT CHAT only for the 
   customers based on your logic.

For help on Development, please refer below link: 
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf